# Mongoid Query DB by Virtual Attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid, mongoid3

**BACKGROUND:** I have Posts and Users, both of which HABTM Communities. In my Post model, I have a method for calculating a post's relevance to a given user by comparing how many communities they have in common as such:

```
def relevance(user)
  (self.communities & user.communities).length
end
```

**OBJECTIVE:** To query Posts either by a given relevance i.e.

```
Post.where(:relevance => 3)
```

or

to query all posts and sort them by relevance i.e.

```
Post.all.desc(:relevance)
```

I know that the user variable is needed there somewhere, just wondering if something like this is possible or if a workaround exists.

Comment: I fear you won't be able to do that directly. But you could use some map/reduce processing.

Comment: Can you expand a little I am unsure exactly what you are trying to accomplish. Where is relevance calculated and does it already exist in the document?

Comment: Relevance is calculated as a method in post.rb (see code above) since it is different for each user and must be calculated on the fly.

Comment: Ah ok so you scroll through each post assigning this function and now you want to sortt hem by that function. MongoDB does not natively support this in their drivers I believe so you might need to find a function that will do this for you, probably a quicksort function in ruby. I personally do not know of one since I am not a ruby programmer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in mongoDB using [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) (new in version 2.2).

You have to have the array of User's communities available.  I'll call it userComms in this example - I'm expecting it to be an array with the same type of values that posts.communities are.

```
db.posts.aggregate( [
    {
        "$unwind" : "$communities"
    },
    {
        "$match" : {
            "communities" : {
                "$in" : userComms
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : "$_id",
            "relevance" : {
                "$sum" : 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$sort" : {
            "relevance" : -1
        }
    }
]);
```

This returns a document of the form:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "relevance" : 4
        },
        {
            "_id" : 6,
            "relevance" : 3
        },
...
        ]
}
```

The result array contains _ids of posts and relevant as computed by adding the number of communities they had in common with user.  Then it's sorted (descending) by that sum.

Comment: Having just started with Mongo, I've been searching for how to implement this using Mongoid - though I'm not sure it's possible yet. Any advice re: doing this w/ Mongoid?

Comment: You can use db.runCommand({aggregate:"collectionname",pipeline:[...]}) to execute any aggregation framework pipeline

Comment: Thanks, the issue I'm having with this approach is that a post's relevance is different for each user. Meaning it requires the current_user object in order to be calculated. Any thoughts on how this can be done?

Comment: that's what "userComms" represents in my examples.  You read user's communities into an array and use it as a parameter to this query and the response will be valid _for this user only_ and only "now".