# Order_by mongo query with multiple model fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I am building a index controller that implements filtering and ordering capabilities.

My first interrogation relates to ordering:

my model defines 2 boolean fields that we can refer to as priorities as so:

```
field :domination, type: Boolean, default: false
field :critical_alert, type: Boolean, default: false
```

The frontend exposes 3 priority levels (front most to least important):
 - critical_alert (filter items that have this flag set to true) 
 - domination (filter items that have this flag set to true)
 - normal (elements that have none of these 2 fields set to true)

Imagine there is a `order_by` feature exposed and that we want to filter by priority.

In that context, `order_by:asc` would result in items being ordered as such:
 **critical_alert** then **domination** then **normal** priority items.

My first idea was to partition the results into each group, and merge then with the correct order as such:

```
## Event has a filterable concern that implements the filter method
partition = {}
partition[:critical] = Event.filter(filtering_params(params)).select {|e| e.critical_alert}
partition[:domination] = Event.filter(filtering_params(params)).select {|e| e.domination}
partition[:normal] = Event.filter(filtering_params(params)).select {|e| !e.domination and !e.critical_alert}
pageable = partition[:critical] + partition[:domination] + partition[:normal]
```

My problem is that I also need the results to be paginated. It seems like the page method is only available on activeRecord instances. I am kind of stomped. Building filters that apply directly to 1 attribute is fine, but this is a little out of the norm.

**Side Question**: Is the controller an appropriate place to have this logic?

Is there a way to achieve this in a clean way, meaning leveraging as much as possible of the rails features if possible?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do (as usual with MongoDB) is to add another field that hides the computation so that you don't need to try anything fancy in the actual queries. Suppose we call this the "status":

```
field :status, :type => Integer
```

Then whenever `domination` or `critical_alert` change (or when you create a new `Event`), you can recompute the `status`:

```
def recompute_status
    if(critical_alert)
        self.status = 0
    elsif(domination)
        self.status = 1
    else
        self.status = 2
    end
end
```

Once you have that you can `.asc(:status)` or `.desc(:status)` to get things in the desired order.

Comment: according to this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164876/mongoid-query-db-by-virtual-attribute), it's not possible. Any thoughts? . I tried it without much success.

Comment: `field :status` means that it is a real field in the document. Having multiple copies of things in the database is standard procedure with MongoDB.